# I ruined my dumplings in the crock pot

Tags: crockpot, dumplings

I made chicken and gravy in the crock pot. Later on I decided to add dumplings., for the next night. It wasn't hot, I figured it would soak up all the juices for cooking in the morning. Needless to say, my dumplings broke down they are stretchy and messy. Is it ruined now. Can I salvage my meal?

Answer (score 1):

Salvage means different things, if you want to make it presentable at a fashionable dinner party then probably not, if you want to make it good enough for a family meal then you should be ok. It's still edible at the end of the day, it's not as if broken down dumplings are bad for you.

It all depends on how broken down the dumplings have gotten. If they are in reasonable chunks then get yourself a slotted spoon and get to work, you should be able to get it pretty decent looking. If they are really fine then you will need to sieve the liquid through a fine strainer to get them out. That will be time consuming as you will need to separate the good stuff you want to keep from the stuff you want to strain.